# Java Swing. Лагает анимация на Linux

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, swing, awt

Есть очень простенькое приложение с интерфейсом на *Java* с использованием *Swing*. Его смысл — считывать нажатия на клавиши и менять координаты отрисовки квадратика. Вся проблема в том, что на *Ubuntu* анимация ужасно тормозит, а вот на *Windows* все плавно летает.
В чем может быть проблема? В ос или в приложении?

P.s - код писал не я

**View:**

```
class View extends JComponent implements ActionListener
{
    private Timer timer;
    private int repaintsPerSecond;

    public View()
    {
        repaintsPerSecond = 30;
        timer = new Timer(1000 / repaintsPerSecond, this);
    }

    public void start()
    {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        timer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        Player p;
        Point loc;
        int s;
        for(int i = 0; i < Main.players.size(); i++)
        {
            p = Main.players.get(i);
            loc = p.getLocation();
            s = p.getSize();
            g.setColor(p.getColor());
            g.fillRect((int)loc.getX(), (int)loc.getY(), s, s);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class Controller implements KeyListener, ActionListener
{
    public View v;

    private Player player;
    private Timer timer;
    private boolean isUp, isLeft, isRight, isDown;

    public Controller(Player player, int delay)
    {
        this.player = player;
        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
    }

    public void start()
    {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        timer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(isUp)
            player.stepUp();
        if(isLeft)
            player.stepLeft();
        if(isRight)
            player.stepRight();
        if(isDown)
            player.stepDown();
        v.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {       
        switch(e.getKeyCode())
        {
            case 87://w
                isUp = true;
                break;
            case 65://a
                isLeft = true;
                break;
            case 68://d
                isRight = true;
                break;
            case 83://s
                isDown = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        switch(e.getKeyCode())
        {
            case 87://w
                isUp = false;
                break;
            case 65://a
                isLeft = false;
                break;
            case 68://d
                isRight = false;
                break;
            case 83://s
                isDown = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Экстрасенсы в отпуске, телепаты тоже. - код в студию. Прямо в вопрос добавьте, через кнопочку `править`.

Comment: @And, вместо `\`править\`` можно было написать `[edit]` — это было бы сразу и ссылкой для редактирования. для тренировки: [edit]

Comment: А разве у `Timer` есть метод `stop` ? Вы пробовали использовать логирование (`LogManager`), и отладку кода?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена переходом с *Swing* на *JavaFX*... к черту этот древний костыль.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте следующее, в метод paintComponent(Graphics g) добавить строку Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync(); 
Примерно так:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    Player p;
    Point loc;
    int s;
    for(int i = 0; i < Main.players.size(); i++)
    {
        p = Main.players.get(i);
        loc = p.getLocation();
        s = p.getSize();
        g.setColor(p.getColor());
        g.fillRect((int)loc.getX(), (int)loc.getY(), s, s);
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();

}
```